# Stop Meteor on windows? With cygwin?

Tags: windows, meteor, cygwin

I am using Meteor on windows with cygwin, and after executing "meteor help" I was surprised to see that no command to stop the server was available. Hitting ctrl+c did not stop it. I can't find any process called node or meteor. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

read more about `Ctr + C` and `Ctr + Z` in [here](https://superuser.com/questions/262942/whats-different-between-ctrlz-and-ctrlc-in-unix-command-line)
and the reason for `cygwin` in [here](https://superuser.com/questions/580816/why-can-i-only-suspend-using-ctrl-z-in-screen-under-cygwin)

Comment: the last link does not work... also, ctr+c is useless to me if I run "meteor &", there has to be a way to stop Meteor besides ctr+c

Comment: if you run `meteor &`, the current process is not on the terminal anymore. Obviously, pressing Ctr + C will not help. Only triggering the kill command will actually kill the process in this case. You need to update the question with the `meteor &`. This is a totally different case

Comment: That is not what I am concerned about, I want to know how to kill the process in cygwin. If I was on a linux box I would use ps -ef | grep meteor or node and I would just kill the process no big deal. I am surprised that there is no command to kill the meteor process?